# how to constrain size of youtube embed iframe size?

Tags: php, html, iframe, youtube, embed

The youtube embed code's general structure is like this:

`<iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MiYND_zvIc0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I want users to upload this code to my SQL table and then I will retrieve and output all the embed codes from the SQL table. The problem is that I have no choice as to what width or height the iframe is going to be since the users are making the embed codes through youtube's site.

Let's say I have 20 instances of the code I posted above and I want to auto-resize all the iframes to 640 x 480 when they get retrieved. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function with [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to grab and save 3 things in you database:

- youtube id
- width
- height

second, use [substr_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) function to change the value of all instances depending on your needs